# Subclassing a list in Python. Why does slice and empty list not work?

Tags: python, list, subclass

I am befuddled over what I think is a very simple and straight forward subclass of a list in Python.

Suppose I want all the functionality of list. I want to add several methods to the default set of a list.

The following is an example:

```
class Mylist(list):

    def cm1(self):
        self[0]=10

    def cm2(self):
        for i,v in enumerate(self):
            self[i]=self[i]+10        

    def cm3(self):
        self=[]         

    def cm4(self):
        self=self[::-1]

    def cm5(self):
        self=[1,2,3,4,5]       

ml=Mylist([1,2,3,4])
ml.append(5)
print "ml, an instance of Mylist: ",ml
ml.cm1()
print "cm1() works: ",ml

ml.cm2()
print "cm2() works: ",ml

ml.cm3() 
print "cm3() does NOT work as expected: ",ml     

ml.cm4()
print "cm4() does NOT work as expected: ",ml     

ml.cm5()
print "cm5() does NOT work as expected: ",ml
```

The output:

```
Mylist:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cm1() works:  [10, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cm2() works:  [20, 12, 13, 14, 15]
cm3() does NOT work as expected:  [20, 12, 13, 14, 15]
cm4() does NOT work as expected:  [20, 12, 13, 14, 15]
cm5() does NOT work as expected:  [20, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

So it seems that a scalar assignment works as I expect and understand. List or slices do not work as I understand. By 'does not work,' I mean that the code in the method does not change the instance of ml as the first two methods do.

What do I need to do so that `cm3()` `cm4()` and `cm5()` work?

Comment: It's not specific to lists. It's how names and assignment work in Python — assignment rebinds the name, and never modifies the object the name is currently bound to.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Yes, I suspected that and understand. Surely it is possible to reassign a subclassed list or use slice syntax?  I just do not know how and cannot find via goggle or Python docs. I am a little green on Python classes still...

Comment: It depends on what you expect "reassign" to mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that in `cm3`, `cm4`, and `cm5`, you are not modifying the object! You are creating a new one in the scope of the member function, and then assigning it to self. The outer scope doesn't respect this. In `cm1` and `cm2`, you are modifying the same object, so the object stays the same.

Try using the `id` function to debug this:

```
def cm4(self):
    self=self[::-1]
    print 'DEBUG', id(self)

...

m1.cm4()
print 'DEBUG', id(self)
```

You'll see that the `id` is different.

So, you might ask, well how do I do this? You are lucky that with lists you can assign into a splice. This might not be as easy with other data structures. What this does is keeps the same list, but replaces the items. To do this, do:

```
self[:] = ...
```

So, for example:

```
self[:] = self[::-1]
```

Comment: This is why `self` has to be in the signature of member functions (you can call it whatever you want, as long as its the first position).  Behind the scenes, `ml.cm3` gets turned into `cm3(ml)` (if there are arguments, they each get pushed back a position).  So `self` is pass-by-reference just like other object arguments, and you're just changing your local reference.

Answer (score 4):

Your misunderstanding is that there is something special about the word `self`.  In those methods it is just a name in scope like any other name in python, so when you reassign it, you are just rebinding the name `self` to some other object - not mutating the parent object.  In fact that argument doesn't even need to be named `self`, that is only a convention that python programmers use.

Here is reimplementation of your members to mutate properly:

```
def cm3(self):
  self[:] = []

def cm4(self):
  self.reverse()

def cm5(self):
  self[:] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

use `self[:]` instead of self, `self = ...` will rebind self variable to other object only, that will not change the list object.

```
def cm3(self):
    self[:]=[]         

def cm4(self):
    self[:]=self[::-1]

def cm5(self):
    self[:]=[1,2,3,4,5]
```